# Does ibuprofen improve healing or only helps with pain?

Tags: inflammation, self-healing-repairing, anti-inflammatory

I've noticed several times that ibuprofen is recommended for injuries or pain resulting from inflammation, such as knee or shoulder pain for example. This presumably is because of the anti-inflammatory (side?) effects of this pain medication.

My question is: is the point of this situation in order to deal with the pain caused by the inflammation by reducing the inflammation? or is to reduce the inflammation to improve the healing?

The reason I'm doubtful about the latter is because usually if your body is doing something (inflamming) it is in order to facilitate healing. (obviously there are counter examples too though). So would going against the body's natural reaction in this case improve or hinder healing?

Also I would imagine that reducing pain would improve the use or range of the joint, which would also have some sort of effect. Ie if you move the joint around more it would probably facilitate healing better, but I am more asking about the effects of the inflammation.

Comment: Ibuprofen is an *NSAID* which stands for *Non-Steroidal Anti-Inflammatory Drug*. If you google something to the effect of mechanism of action of NSAIDs, you might find the answer, or if you still have questions, please edit what you have found (quote and link are great) and we'll try to help. Thanks.

Comment: @anongoodnurse omg thank you, i searched so much for ibuprofen and couldn't find anything, but switching it out for nsaid immediately comes up with multiple results.

Comment: and looking at a couple of studies; basically the scientific consensus is "lol dunno, maybe, maybe not"

Comment: It really depends (which basically is the scientific consensus anyways for everything xD): For example, for lower back pain some national guidelines recommend taking NSAIDs and encourage patients to be active, since lower back pain has a benign prognosis - BUT if you do not move or shift your posture to avoid the pain this can and will lead to secondary muscle strains and prolong the period of healing. (but there are different attitudes by different health care systems on that AFAIK [@anongoodnurse ;) ] ).

Comment: However, a lot of times inflammation is also sterile, meaning there is no infectious disease that leads to an immune response but the immune system is misguided or irritated. In these cases, NSAIDs can be a treatment of the "over-active" immune system (they are for example even called "Non-steroid anti-rheumatic drugs" in some languages). Very much citation needed, but I would expect that sterile immune responses outnumber infectious immune reactions in high-income countries.

Comment: @Narusan - With lower back pain, *move!* You'll get no argument from me there.

Comment: My unresearched opinion, so not an answer: The idea, in *very* broad strokes, is that the painful inflammation that we treat with NSAIDs is the prolonged type that impedes healing. A healthy amount of inflammation is crucial to the normal healing process. The medical consensus is NSAIDs merely treat the pain and the unnecessary inflammation, but they do not help 'healing', for example, when used for chronic pain (e.g. knee osteoarthritis) they do not prevent long-term accumulative damages to the knee structure. There are articles that claim otherwise, but they're preliminary, to put it mildly.